# Permutations[] runtime in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, permutation, combinatorics

It seems to run very fast, even for relatively large (size 10) sets. Can anyone tell me the big-theta runtime of their particular algorithm? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where WRI puts the Big O, Omega, Theta run times of any of the Mathematica algorithms in the documentation?

Comment: No, but for some functions they do explain the underlying implementations (this function calls a C-library which uses hash maps, etc...)

Comment: Can this possibly run faster than O(n!) considering that's the number of sets generated?  Or you're interested in how much slower it is than O(n!)? (It needs to do extra comparisons, as it won't return the same for `{1,2,2}` as for `{1,2,3}`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first attempt at answering this was badly flawed. Since the most of the internal algorithms have no posted limiting behavior, I decide to measure this directly.  I measured thetime it takes to calculate the `Permutations` of a random list of values, and calculated the average and standard deviation over a 1000 of them for each length. I used a maximum length of 10 elements due to time required, and that `Permutations` only works lists up to length 12.  My results on a log plot:

[image: log plot of permutation timings up to length 10]

The mean is the black line, and one standard deviation is represented by the filled region surrounding the mean.  Starting at length 5, it is roughly straight until 10 where a slight curve can be detected. I'd suspect it is O(n!), but for lengths below 7 or 8, it really won't matter.  Even permutations of length 10 gave a respectable showing averaging at 0.241 +/- 0.012 s.

Comment: Instead of plotting on log scale, can you divide by `n!` so we can see how much slower it is than that?

Comment: I just noticed that *both* your axes are logarithmic.  You only meant to use a log vertical axis, right?  Otherwise an exponential will curve upwards.

Comment: Assuming an `n!` complexity, this should give comparable timings for all `k`, which it does for `k >= 5`.  So the complexity is close to `n!` indeed.  It gives larger timings for `k < 5`, but that might be due to other effects.  `Table[{k, 
  First@Timing[Do[Permutations@Range[k], {10*(10!/k!)}];]}, {k, 5, 
  10}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs, changed to log-plot. When you say divide by `n!` are you referring to dividing by the timing or `n!` itself? Second, I don't understand why your varying the number of `Permutations` the way you do, can you explain?

Comment: my hypothesis is that the running time is either proportional to n! (because in total n! permutations are generated) or slower (because of the extra comparisons needed when there are equal elements in the list).  Therefore what I'd like to know is how much slower the algorithm is than n!.  So ideally I'd take a number of timings for n=1..10, and divide each by n!.  If it runs indeed in n! time, we'd get the same value for each.  But this is impractical since e.g. the time for n=10 is expected to be 10!/5! ~= 30000 times slower than for n=5.

Comment: @rcollyier Very short timings can't be measured precisely, especially on Windows where AFAIK the timer resolution is 15 msec.  But a running time of approx 1 sec is ideal for measurement because it's both precise (1 sec = many times 15 msec) and short.  So instead of dividing each timing by n!, I ran the piece of code as many times for each `n` as necessary in order get exactly the same time **if** the complexity is indeed n!.  If we don't get the same time, but larger and larger for increasing `n`, then the complexity is worse than n!.  Hope that's clear, comments can only be very short here.